# Do html form visit the page specified?

Tags: php, html, forms

When you click the submit button in a html form do the form visit the page specified and does not send a separate request?

The reason I'm asking is that when I use forms to submit data, the php variables that are set in the request are available to the page compared to when I send an Ajax I have to manually handle the return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, submitting an HTML form (and not intercepting the submit event with JS) will construct an HTTP request using the data in the form and then cause the browser to navigate to the page returned by the request.

Making a request using Ajax doesn't cause the browser to navigate at all (which is the point of Ajax, it handles the request and response with JS instead of navigating).

Comment: Ah, thank you. That was the part I failed to get when it came to the difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

From the server point of view, it doesn't care if the request was sent through ajax or not. It will send back what ever it has been programmed to return (an html page, json data or even a string)

From the browser point of view, if you send an ajax request it sort of goes behind the sceens and you have to take care of whatever is returned by the server. On the other hand, it if is a "normal" browser request then the browser receives and display what the server sends back.

Answer (score 0):

As best I understand your question - yes the php variables in the form will be "available to the page" using `$_POST["nameOfInput"]` you can access these variables.